# Does "key " in the function have the same meaning?

Tags: c++

```
TreeNode *& BST::_find(TreeNode *& root, const K & key) const {
    if (root == NULL || key == root->key) {
        return root; //root is null when we cannot find
    }
    if (key < root->key) {
        return _find(root->left, key);
    }
    if (key > root->key) {
        return _find(root->right, key);
    }
```

For this find function in BST, how to understand `key < root->key`, are these two `key` different or not?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understood your question, but I hope this helps you:

In general, the given `key` and `root->key` are not the same object, if that is what confuses you. `root->key` accesses the member variable `TreeNode::key`, where `key` is the given function argument.

If that is clear and you're asking if the values of the two keys are different when you hit the line `if (key < root->key)`, the answer is yes. Since `key == root->key` handles the equality-case, they are different in the following if clauses, i.e. `key` must be less or greater than `root->key`. Depending on the particular case either the `left` or the `right` node is returned.